# date() and now() functions no longer working in query criteria

Tags: ms-access

I have looked into the references and do not see any libraries with "MISSING" at the end (see image below).

[image: list of references that are currently used]

I unchecked and checked the references above that are in use, and that didn't change anything. I then tried to compile the database, and that didn't resolve the issue. I also tried creating a new database and importing all tables, queries, etc. but ran into an error that states "one or more of the newly created objects contain a data type that isn't compatible with earlier versions of access." Is it possible that this is due to updating to datetime2 from datetime? I believe I accepted that change when creating date fields in the Microsoft SQL server management studio.

update: now it appears any criteria associated with using dates is not working. I can't even run a query with the following criteria on a date field:

```
Between [start_date] And [end_date]
```

Comment: You should avoid the _DateTime2_ in SQL Server if at all possible. Change the fields back to _DateTime_, and you should be set.

Comment: This post looks like it will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72649543/ssma-unable-to-convert-date-time-in-ms-access-to-datetime-in-sql-server

Comment: @Gustav thanks so much for pointing this out. It turns out there were LOTS of fields to convert back to datetime. I've done this on a test server, and have not yet pushed the changes to production. Before pushing to production, I'd like to make sure there won't be major data loss. We don't really store any time values - I'm practically 100% certain on this and have talked to team members as well. So the conversion back to DateTime shouldn't really result in any data loss right? Assuming storage of Time is actually not important to us, this conversion back to DateTime should not hurt anything.